# Add JSON entry into an array to use in ListView

Tags: java, android

I have the following code which gets the number how many times a select entry appears:

```
int k = 0;
             int j = 0;
             try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i); // get the josn object
                    if(jsonObj.getString("type").equals("image")) { // compare for the key-value
                        k++;
                    }
                    if(jsonObj.getString("type").equals("text")) { // compare for the key-value
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(k), 2000).show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(j), 2000).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

My JSON file is:

```
[
    {
        "id": "12",
        "type": "text",
        "data": "This is a test"
    },
    {
        "id": "5465465",
        "type": "image",
        "data": "http://pagesbyz.com/theImages/gallery/portfolio_app07.png"
    },
    {
        "id": "982",
        "type": "text",
        "data": "THIS IS A TEST TEXT"
    },
    {
        "id": "5500",
        "type": "text",
        "data": "http://pagesbyz.com/theImages/gallery/portfolio_app03.png"
    }
]
```

So... `k = 1` and `j = 3`

How can I get the entire array for the matched entry?

For example once the type equals `image` I want an array set up to hold the information.

How do I translate the following in Java?

```
for (as many times an "image" entry appears) {
    if ( type == "image") {
         imgarr[index found][id] = "5465465";
         imgarr[index found][type] = "image";
         imgarr[index found][data] = "http://pagesbyz.com/theImages/gallery/portfolio_app07.png";
    }
}

for (as many times an "text" entry appears) {
    if ( type == "text") {
         txtarr[index found][id] = "12";
         txtarr[index found][type] = "text";
         txtarr[index found][data] = "This is a test";

        txtarr[index found][id] = "082";
        txtarr[index found][id] = "text";
        txtarr[index found][id] = "THIS IS A TEST TEXT";

        and so forth...
    }
}
```

And the same for type equals "text"?

Comment: from what i understood, you can create a new JSONArray and whenever it matches add the entry to this array when the loop is finished. all the matched entries will be found in the new JSONArray..

Comment: Yes pretty much, How do I accomplish that? Because I want to create a listview of the data found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create 2 new jsonArray variables, one for image and one for type, whenever the type is image add the object to jsonimage and same for jsontext

```
       try {
            JSONArray jsonimage = new JSONArray();
            JSONArray jsontext = new JSONArray();
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)jsonArray.get(i); // get the josn object
                if(jsonObj.getString("type").equals("image")) { // compare for the key-value

                    jsonimage.put(jsonObj);
                    k++;

                }
                if(jsonObj.getString("type").equals("text")) { // compare for the key-value
                    jsontext.put(jsonObj);
                    j++;
                }
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(k), 2000).show();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(j), 2000).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

hope this is what you are looking for or give you a hint.

EDIT:

to add the jsonArray to the listview, you can either create a hashMap or simply create String of strings for each entry in the JSONArray.

```
       String sId = new String[jsonimage.length()];
        String sType = new String[jsonimage.length()];
        String sData = new String[jsonimage.length()];
for (int i = 0 ; i < jsonimage.length(); i++)
        {
            JSONObject c = jsonimage.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = c.getString("id");
            String type = c.getString("type");
            String data = c.getString("data");



            sId[i] = id;
            sType[i] = type;
            sData[i] = data;                

        }
```

then after you having your data from the JSONArray...

have a custom view that holds 3 textview and add this

```
listView.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(yourClass.this));
```

and simply add the generated String[position] in getView of the CustomAdapter

Comment: Thanks. Now how would I retrieve the array if I wanted to add it to a listview?